# Rich snippet display issue in google search

Tags: seo, microdata, rich-snippets

Rich snippets is not working in as google says though it can recognize all of the information in structured data section of the following tool. I am using schema.org sites Place type. Is it the issue? If so, then what should I use in my situation. I need to show the following information given in the image. Most important part is to display image of the Place.

*.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets.

### Extracted structured data

Item 
type:   *://schema.org/place

property:
url:    *://condonow.com/Toronto--New-Condos--Plaza-Developments--Musée

image:  *://condonow.com/Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?imageID=55174
telephone:  416-862-0888
name:   Musée
description:    Toronto - New Condos - Plaza Developments - Musée - Overview

Item 
type:   *://schema.org/postaladdress

property:
name:   Address
streetaddress:  525 Adelaide St W
postalcode: M5V 1T4
addressregion:  ON
addresslocality:    Toronto

Item 
type:   *://schema.org/geocoordinates

property:
latitude:   43.6452196
longitude:  -79.40313659999998

Item 
type:   *://schema.org/event

property:
name:   Worksheet Submission
startdate:  04/19/2013 09:00 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it takes time to re-index your website for search engines. The changes in the search results (not rich snippet testing tool) might show after few days. However, in my opinion the main reason why it doesn't show up in the search results is that Google search engine doesn't support that type of content.

### Google Search Engine Supports:

- Reviews
- People
- Products
- Businesses and organizations
- Recipes
- Events
- Music
- Applications
- Video
- Breadcrumbs

You can read more about these content types and what type of content Google search engine supports at here -http://blog.victorlava.com/what-is-a-rich-snippet-everything/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Let me check the link.

Answer (score 1):

I see three issues here.

First, AFAIK there is no Rich Snippets in Google *Web* Search for organizations (pls, look at the [docs](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146861&topic=1088474&ctx=topic)). So the only thing you may expect - is some kind of Rich Snippets in Local Search ([docs](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/richsnippetslocal/)).

Second, organizations markup (and Local Search itself) is about, well, organizations - services, businesses, etc. As I get from your site you have real estate listings - it's different. So I'm not sure that you can get any type of rich snippet at all.

Third, at [page](http://condonow.com/Toronto--New-Condos--Plaza-Developments--Mus%C3%A9e) you have four *separate* objects (place, postaladdress, geocoordinates, event). Currently there is no way to figure out connection between them. I suppose you wanted to indicate that you have this object (musee) at this address (Toronto, ...) with this geo (lat, long). I'd recommend to use nested items instead (e.g., put address inside Place using itemprop). *Maybe* (I'm not sure) it'd be better for you to use schema.org/Organization. But as I said it's likely enough that  you just can't get anything for you listings either way.

BTW I'm not from Google and it'd better to get answer from someone there.

Comment: I am also thinking about using schema.org/Organization.